# SSH public key auth fails when UsePAM is set to "no"

Tags: linux, ssh

To disable password auth I've set the following values in my `sshd_config`

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

When I try to log in with my private key I get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I then change `UsePAM` to `yes` I can login using my private key. Why?

I'm connecting to a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit host from OSX

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/deploy -l deploy localhost -p 2222 -v
```

here's the verbose `ssh` output:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/<user>/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>/.ssh/deploy type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>/.ssh/deploy-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 50:db:75:ba:11:2f:43:c9:ab:14:40:6d:7f:a1:ee:e3
debug1: Host '[localhost]:2222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/key1
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/deploy
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Did you run sshd in debug mode and check the log it generates?

Comment: We're definitely going to need more logs. I replicated your situation in a VM (using Fedora 17) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module) more complicated ssh configuration is required to authenticate.  You're looking for this, actually:

```
# grep Password /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

This will disable passworded login.  Ensure you public key settings correctly established.

Comment: This isn't really true. In fact, many guides recommend setting `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`, `PasswordAuthentication`, and `UsePAM` all to `no` and using only public key authentication. I've never worked in such an environment, so I can't easily give a real reason why it's not working quite  yet.

Comment: Thats why I set it to no in the first place, because every guide I found did it!

Comment: I'll stand corrected; you're correct, Scott.  That said, if he doesn't wish to use pam_unix, he'll need to configure pam_nologin (or allow root access.)  http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/sles9/adminguide-sles9/ch20s02.html

Comment: Just go for the most `no` and the least possible `yes`.

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-redhat.conf; sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`


`ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`
`PasswordAuthentication no`
`PermitEmptyPasswords no`
`PubkeyAuthentication yes`
`UsePAM no`


...enables you to login with your private key only and even though the user has a password, the password login is always denied.

Answer (score 13):

Is your user account locked? You can either unlock the user account

`passwd -u username`

or lock the user account but enable PAM:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: Plus, `passwd -u` fail if user has empty password. Use `echo username:$(head -c12 /dev/urandom |base64) |chpasswd` to set random valid password.

Comment: `usermod -p '*' username` will let you have all three set to "no", and a still allow "username" to connect using public key authentication without having to set a throwaway password.